# Bash sort an array of numbers with continuous steps

Tags: arrays, bash, sorting, numbers

I have a bash array of number for example

```
a=( 1 6 8 15 22 32 34 36 24 25 26)
```

The expected sorted result should be

```
b=(24 25 26; 32 34 36; 1 8 15 22; 6)
```

i.e. the continuous numbers with step 1 first `(24 25 26)`, the continuous numbers with step 2 follows `(32 34 36)` and then the continuous numbers with step 3 etc. The final ones are those that can not form a continuous sequence of 3 or more numbers.

```
function group_jobs_for_pbs {
    local jobnos=("${@}")

    # Sort job nos
    IFS=$'\n' origjobstr="${jobnos[*]}"; unset IFS
    #mapfile -t sortedjobno < <(sort -g <<<"${origjobstr}")
    while IFS='' read -r line; do sortedjobno+=("$line"); done < <(sort -g <<<"${origjobstr}")

    # Find continous job nos
    local ars=()
    local sortedar=("${sortedjobno[@]}")

    local ar2=()
    # shellcheck disable=SC2206
    if [[ ${#sortedar[@]} -lt 3 ]]; then
        ar2+=("${sortedar[@]}")
    else
        for step in $(seq 1 10); do

            if [[ ${#sortedar[@]} -lt 3 ]]; then break; fi

            local prev=0
            local ar1=()
            ar2=()
            for curr in "${sortedar[@]}"; do
                #echo "step: $step, curr=$curr: ${ar1[*]}; ${ar2[*]}; ${ars[*]}"
                if (( 10#$curr == (10#$prev+step) )); then
                    ar1+=("$curr")
                else
                    #echo "step: $step; curr=$curr, ${ar1[*]}"
                    if [[ ${#ar1[@]} -ge 3 ]]; then
                        ars+=("${ar1[*]}");
                    elif [[ ${#ar1[@]} -gt 0 ]]; then
                        ar2+=(${ar1[@]})
                    fi
                    ar1=("$curr")
                fi
                prev=${curr}
            done
            if [[ ${#ar1[@]} -ge 3 ]]; then
                ars+=("${ar1[*]}");
            elif [[ ${#ar1[@]} -gt 0 ]]; then
                ar2+=(${ar1[@]})
            fi
            #echo "stepB: $step, ${ar1[*]}; ${ar2[*]}; ${ars[*]}"

            # sorted all elements that are not grouped
            #IFS=$'\n' origjobstr="${ar2[*]}"; unset IFS
            #mapfile -t sortedar < <(sort -g <<<"${origjobstr}")
            #while IFS='' read -r line; do sortedar+=("$line"); done < <(sort -g <<<"${origjobstr}")
            sortedar=("${ar2[@]}")
        done
    fi

    # every element contains at least two jobs no even they are not continous
    #echo "onejobs = ${ar2[*]}"
    for ((i=0;i<${#ar2[@]};i+=2)); do
        (( j=i+1))
        #echo "$i-$j: ${ar2[i]}, ${ar2[j]}"
        if [[ $j -lt ${#ar2[@]} ]]; then
            ars+=("${ar2[i]} ${ar2[j]}")
        else
            ars+=("${ar2[i]}")
        fi
    done

    #echo "${onejobs[@]}"
    #for ar in "${ars[@]}"; do
    #    echo "ar in newars: ${ar}"
    #done
    IFS=$';' retjobstr="${ars[*]}"; unset IFS    # convert array to string
    echo "${retjobstr}"
}
```

Run this function as `$> group_jobs_for_pbs 1 6 8 15 22 32 34 36 24 25 26` and I got
`24 25 26;32 34 36;8 15 22; 1`.
It seems that 1 is misplaced and 6 is drop incorrectly.

Comment: what should `a=( 99 98 97 4 6 8 3 2 )` become?

Comment: What is the criterion for grouping? Why in your example isn't the first group `1 ... 36`?

Comment: @user1934428 because as stated in the question all members of a group have to be equidistant to their predecessor. And groups with smaller steps come first ...

Comment: @derpirscher: I didn't see the "equidistant" criterium in the question, but I now conclude from your explanation, that "step" means the distance between two numbers. In this case, I wonder how the result should be for `a=( 5 14 5 )`.

Comment: @user1934428 Yes, it's not called "equidistant" in the question. But from the examples and the explanation with "steps" the grouping seems quite clear at least for trivial cases. But yes the question is missing clarity. There are many sequences that may produce ambigous outputs or where one number might belong to one group or another. So I'm voting to close the question in its current state.

Comment: The task is unclear. What happens to the multiples of 6 when I add all multiples of 2 and all multiples of 3 to an array? Are multiples of 6 sorted as multiples of 2? Or 3? Or separately as 6, interrupting the chain of multiples of 2 and 3?

Comment: If you are solving a real world problem, it will also help if you give some use cases where this solution would be helpful. While I up-voted your Q (clean code on a first question, gasp!), I  agree there are seemingly an almost nfinilte set of `prime-number-reductions` (or whatever the correct term is) that complicate solving your problem. So you'll need to devise rules for the mentioned cases OR claim they will never happen. Good luck!

Comment: See [How can I debug a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/4154375) for information about debugging Bash code.  [How can I debug a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/4154375) is similar.

Comment: When I run the `group_jobs_for_pbs 1 6 8 15 22 32 34 36 24 25 26` with the function definition in the  question I get output `24 25 26;32 34 36;8 15 22;1 6`.  I.e. the `6` is not dropped.  The reason the `1` is misplaced is that the code only considers adjacent elements in the remaining sorted list when looking for steps of  a particular size.  The remaining list when looking for steps of size 7 is `(1 6 8 ...)`, so the step from `1` to the next element is 5 and it is not included  in the list of elements with steps of size 7.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question is exceptional, particularly for a new contributor, because it makes a reasonable attempt at solving the problem, it is fairly well structured, and (very exceptionally) it is [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean.  Easy improvements would be to use more meaningful variable names and remove the commented-out code.

I explained in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77637167/bash-sort-an-array-of-numbers-with-continuous-steps#comment136892687_77637167) why the code doesn't produce the desired output.  This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean pure Bash code is an attempt at a full solution:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

readonly kMAX_STEP=10

function group_jobs_for_pbs
{
    local -r jobnums=( "$@" )

    # Add the job numbers to a sparse array, `jobset`, that represents a set
    # of job numbers to be checked for same-step sequences.
    # `jobset` indices are job numbers.
    # `jobset` values are the number 1 (which is TRUE in logical expressions).
    # Code below depends on the fact that Bash expands the list of
    # array indices (`${!jobset[@]}`) in sorted order, small to large.
    local j jobset=()
    for j in "${jobnums[@]}"; do
        # Verify that job numbers are valid
        [[ -z $j || $j == *[^[:digit:]]* ]] && die "non-numeric argument: $j"
        [[ $j == 0*[^0]* ]] && die "unsupported octal argument: $j"
        (( ${jobset[j]-0} )) && die "Repeated number in jobs list: $j"

        jobset[j]=1
    done

    # Check for sequences with each possible step size up to $kMAX_STEP
    local step k sequence_jobs retjobstr=''
    for ((step=1; step<=kMAX_STEP; step++)); do
        for j in "${!jobset[@]}"; do
            # Look for a sequence of job numbers, separated by the current
            # step, starting at the current job number
            sequence_jobs=()
            for ((k=j; ${jobset[k]-0}; k+=step)); do
                sequence_jobs+=( "$k" )
            done

            # If a sequence of jobs has been found, add the jobs to the
            # return string and remove them from the set of jobs to be checked
            if (( ${#sequence_jobs[*]} > 2 )); then
                retjobstr+=';'
                for k in "${sequence_jobs[@]}"; do
                    retjobstr+=" $k"
                    unset 'jobset[k]'
                done
            fi
        done
    done

    # Add jobs not in any sequence to the return string
    if (( ${#jobset[*]} > 0 )); then
        retjobstr+=';'
        for j in "${!jobset[@]}"; do
            retjobstr+=" $j"
        done
    fi

    printf '%s\n' "${retjobstr#; }"

    return 0
}

function die
{
    local -r msg=$1

    printf '%s: ERROR: %s\n' "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" "$msg"
    exit 1
}

group_jobs_for_pbs 1 6 8 15 22 32 34 36 24 25 26
```

- When the code is run it outputs `24 25 26; 32 34 36; 1 8 15 22; 6`.
- When the function call is changed to `group_jobs_for_pbs 99 98 97 4 6 8 3 2` (as suggested by @jhnc) it outputs `2 3 4; 97 98 99; 6 8`.  That may not be what you want.
- The code requires arguments to the function to be distinct non-negative decimal integers.  The function includes basic sanity checks on the arguments.

Be aware that, even if it does what you want, the code is an exercise in perversity.  Bash is a very unsuitable tool for problems like this.  Python would be an immeasurably better option.